# PHP PDO statement: quotes within quotes cause query to fail

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo, escaping

I am attempting the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date 
                      BETWEEN :year-:month-01 AND :year-:month-01 +
                      INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
$stmt->bindValue(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':month', $_POST["month"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When `$year` equals 2015 and `$_POST["month"]` equals 06, the query should give results, but it doesn't. I could make `$year` a `PDO::PARAM_INT`, but this still leaves me with `$_POST["month"]`, which is a string (01 .. 12).

However, when testing with this small adjustment, removing the binds...

```
BETWEEN "2015-06-01" AND "2015-06-01" +
INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
```

The query succeeds and the results show. I think this is because the between-dates that the server receives look like this:

```
'2015'-'06'-01
```

So, my question is as follows:

How do I 'escape' or 'remove' quotes within PDO prepared statements?
There should be an elegant way to solve this.

Comment: Edit, for the record: I forgot to add quotes to my 'adjustment'. Both instances of 2015-06-01 should be in quotes. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother trying to bind parts of a parameter. Also, you cannot re-use named parameters (in most cases), see http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Simply bind the entire value required, eg

```
BETWEEN :start AND :end + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

and...

```
$date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', $year, $month);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $date);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $date);
```

Comment: TBH Phil, I wasn't entirely sure about my answer. I have deleted it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem in an even more elegant way than I suspected was possible.